# Facebook product or app with icon of a black oval

Tags: facebook

Is this last icon a Facebook product?

[image: Facebook app icons]

Comment: The black one is a logo of Oculus VR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black oval is the logo of [Oculus VR](https://www.oculus.com).